# My lap is cold. How can I get ubuntu on my laptop to start generating some heat with minimal effort?

Tags: hardware

Basically I want the CPU and the GPU to start working hard so it heats up my laptop, but not to the point where I can no longer use my laptop. I still need to work on it.

How can I accomplish this without having to install Minecraft or something like that.

Comment: Don't recommend this but go to bios and turn off (or down) the fans, this should cause more heating but could cause overheating if not managed well, also force cpu to max freq with `sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils` then `sudo sed -i 's/^GOVERNOR=.*/GOVERNOR="performance"/' /etc/init.d/cpufrequtils` and finally visit your GPU driver and make it run at maximum performance, with no power saving, should heat that laptop up real nice.

Comment: Also force some fancy effects and compositing to work the gpu `sudo apt-get install compiz-config-settings manager` and run it in dash for more GPU workload

Comment: That should be `sudo apt-get install compiz-config-settings-manager` ran out of editing time

Answer (score 3):

You can overload your CPU, and hence generate heat, by using cpuburn: CPU stress tester for Ubuntu Linux - http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/03/cpuburn-cpu-stress-test-ubuntu-linux/

However if you are wary of running external programs then you can try CPU hammer shell script which uses awk to generate load by doing mathematical calculations http://linux.cloudibee.com/2008/11/linux-cpu-hammer-script/

Hope that helps!

UPDATE: To partially overload the CPU and generate some heat, remove the & at the end of awk script in the second solution:

```
for i in `seq 0 $((NUM_PROC-1))`; do
        awk 'BEGIN {for(i=0;i<10000;i++)for(j=0;j<10000;j++);}' 
done
```

This alternatively loads two of the cores in an old Core2Duo.

To heat your laptop you need to stress at least one core and that may affect performance of certain multi-core applications. If that bothers you then you can make your computer more responsive by adding nice in front of the script as suggested in comment by Charles Boling.

Alternatives:

- Stressing the hard-disk is not a good idea for obvious reason - reduced life.
- Stopping the CPU fan is dangerous and can permanently damage your cpu
- Increasing frequency will increase heat but not all motherboard's allow changing clock frequency and it can be potentially dangerous operation

Comment: One thing to note here is that both of these would use up any CPU resources available making the OP's laptop almost unusable while these are running due to 100% CPU usage, not saying this is wrong, just something to consider.

Comment: cpuburn would be too much. I won't be running it on my laptop for prolonged time. Also won't it affect performance? One idea would be to use cpuburn to heat up one core at a time in a cyclic fasion.

Comment: @mark-kirby , I updated my post to partially load the CPU using the script based solution

Comment: @daltonfury42 Check the update in the answer above. This alternatively load two of my cores in an old Core2Duo and should satisfy what you are looking

Comment: Thats good but stressing some cores would still have a massive effect on performance, mostly multi-threading applications, a way to stress the CPU ( or certain cores) by a percentage of usage or other scaling variable would make this a solid answer. Also what about single core users ( I know it's 2015 but many people still use old computers)

Comment: "nice" the cpu burner to give it lower priority and leave your system more responsive.

Answer (score 1):

By asking this question I assume you do not care about battery backup much. Having said that, CPU Frequency scaling is what you are looking for. Dynamic Frequency Scaling  is a technique by which the frequency of a microprocessor can be automatically adjusted "on the fly," either to conserve power or to reduce the amount of heat generated by the chip. More on this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_scaling).

You can set your CPU scaling governor to 'performance' mode so that it won't dynamically scale down the clock speed:

```
cpufreq-selector --governor="performance"
```

More on this [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling#Scaling_governors).

In this way you can generate **some heat with minimal effort**.

Comment: Do you think this alone would generate heat ? Surly turning up the freq alone would not create heat unless the CPU was performing constant calculations ?

Comment: @markkirby Well, won't running at a high frequency generate heat? Now that you asked, I did some goggling and found out why. [Check it out](https://superuser.com/questions/163567/why-does-the-heat-production-increase-as-the-clockrate-of-a-cpu-increases)!

Comment: OK, I understand why the high freq would make more heat, but my point was more that the CPU must STILL be under stress or the clock will not tick, thus not creating heat, please don't think I am saying you are wrong,  I simply wanted to clarify for others who see this.